# Mostrar mensaje de requerido en un input="select"

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un formulario con la siguiente estructura:

```
<input type="text" required="" />
<select required="required">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Selecciona un ID...</option>
</select>
<input type="text" required="" />
<input type="submit" />
```

Como veran supongo que ya sabran mi problema, de igual forma se los explico... Debo seleccionar un ID y escribir texto, en caso de que uno de estos campos esten vacios salta el mensaje correspondiente al tipo, esto lo hace en el input type="text" esto lo hace bien excepto en el select esto se debe a que al tener el selected="selected" el campo ya no esta vacio, mi pregunta es si existe una forma de verificar que seleccione una opcion diferente a la seleccionada por defecto y en caso de que no seleccione ninguna mostrar el mensaje igual a los otros inputs?

**EDITADO**
[image: Mensaje al no contener informacion el campo]

Comment: ¿Tienes código JavaScript/jQuery? - `" mostrar el mensaje igual a los otros inputs"`, ¿a qué te refieres con eso?

Comment: Te sugiero que edites la pregunta y pongas el código con el que muestras el mensaje de los campos vacíos al darle submit

Comment: No existe ningun codigo, es una propiedad del HTML solo agregando el required="" aparece, agregue una imagen del mensaje.

Comment: @FranciscoFernandez, ¿cuáles son las opciones disponibles en el `select`?

Comment: Sí, puedes usar atributo necesario en HTML5. Pero recuerda, el primer valor debe estar vacío.

Comment: @Mauricio Le asigno las opciones mediante una llamada ajax pero en el HTML tengo la opcion creada por defecto que aparece en el codigo que puse en la pregunta (Con ajax asigno los numeros de ID que encuentre en mi BD).

Comment: @Dev.Joel Ese es el problema, entonces no hay ninguna forma de hacer esto? La unica opcion es tener el select vacio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#mySelect").change(function(event) {
    if($(this)[0].selectedIndex==0)
      {
        $(this).prop('required',true);
        $("#txtFin").val('');
      }
      else
      {
       $(this).prop('required',false);
       $("#txtFin").val($("#mySelect option:selected").val());
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
 <select  id="mySelect" required>
   <option value="">Selecciona un ID...</option>
   <option  value="a">Selecc...</option>
   <option  value="b">Se...</option>
   <option  value="c">Ja</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" id="txtFin" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Funciono perfecto, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Pues bien, aquí te dejo una posible respuesta a tu pregunta. Asumo que trabajas mediante **jQuery**

Esta es una forma de resolverlo.

```js
//Usamos mediante Jquery una funcion que ejecute un algoritmo cuando se inicie el evento submit (enviar) del formulario
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  //Ahora buscamos el select y verificamos que opcion esta elegido
  $("select option:selected",this).each(function (a){
    if(a == 0){ //En dado caso que este elegida la opción 0 (en el indice de los options.
      alert("Por favor elige una Id del Menu Select"); // entonces procedemos a ingresar la alerta 
      $("select").focus(); // Agregamos foco al Select
      return false; //Retornamos falso en formulario para que no permita el envio
    }

  });
  event.preventDefault(); //Detenemos los eventos.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" required="" />
<select> <!-- Primero quitamos todos los atributos del select -->
  <option >Selecciona un ID...</option>
  <option> Opcion Uno</option>
    <option> Opcion Dos</option>
      <option> Opcion Tres</option>
</select>
<input type="text" required="" />
<input type="submit" />
  </form>
```